# Storing a set of days in SQL Table

Tags: database-design

I am using the code first approach and want to create a table called Classes. This table will hold the following information:

- Name   (Math 1)
- Code   (MatA)
- Subject (Mathmatics)
- Description (Math is fun)
- BeginTime  (DateTime)
- EndTime  (DateTime)
- BeginDate  (DateTime)
- EndDate  (DateTime)

In addition to the above, I would like to assign the days a class will happen:

- Name   (Math 1)
- Code   (MatA)
- Subject (Mathmatics)
- Description (Math is fun)
- BeginTime  (DateTime)
- EndTime  (DateTime)
- BeginDate  (DateTime)
- EndDate  (DateTime)
- Monday (bool)
- Tuesday (bool)
- etc.

I do not want to do the above, it just seems inefficient, especially when I need to call a class depending on the current date (ie. Get all classes that appear on Monday).

So, what kind of table structure should I have?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create 2 tables, 1 for `Classes` and 1 for `ClassSchedules`.  Join your tables with a `ClassId` column.

BTW, you shouldn't need 2 columns for `BeginTime` and `BeginDate`, those should be stored in the same column -- same goes for `EndTime` and `EndDate`.

Comment: That's what I thought too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should try the following;

```
CREATE TABLE classes(
Name varchar(255),
Code varchar(255),
Subject varchar(255),
Description varchar(255),
BeginTime date,
EndTime Date,
BeginDate Date,
EndDate Date,
)

CREATE TABLE classdates(
Classname varchar(255),
Classdate varchar(255)
)

Select cl.*,d.classdate from classes cl (nolock)
join classdates d 
on d.classname = cl.classname
```

If you have a large database I would take the first recommendation and add the ClassID along with the name and then join the ClassID after making it a primary key.

Comment: I wouldn't store something called `BeginTime` in a column of type `date`. Did you intend `time`?

Comment: I did not intend time. BeginTime should be a date type and you can format the date when you retrieve it from the Query.

Date will give you much much more flexibility;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx